# Trying to copy strings without last characters using memcpy

Tags: c++

Newbie quetion here.

So i have a const char* and need to copy it to a char* without the last two character.
I already tried to use strncpy but i'm using c++ in vs and says it is deprectated.
I cannot use std::string.
Using memcpy prints me trash. I want to print **adress** but it prints me **adress²²²²Üw**

I will put my code here:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    const char* ident = "adress.P";
    char* tm_name;

    if( (tm_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(ident) - 2))) != NULL)
    memcpy( tm_name, ident, strlen(ident) - 2);

    printf("tm_name = %s", tm_name);
    return 0;
}
```

best regards,
Guilherme Gil

Comment: Are you learning C or C++? `malloc`, `memcpy`, `NULL`, `printf`, and `#include <stdio.h>` aren't what you would typically use in C++.

Comment: `tm_name` is missing a terminating `\0`.

Comment: To `printf` a char buffer that is not nul-terminated use `printf("tm_name = %.*s", strlen(ident) - 2, tm_name);` instead.

Comment: @dxiv Please turn that into an answer, preferrably an explained answer. Maybe a tested explained answer. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Guess I'll leave it as a comment now, and save the [the explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i did not put '\0' xD
thx guys!

Now the code looks like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    const char* ident = "adress.P";
    char* tm_name;


    int ident_size = strlen(ident);
    if ((tm_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ident_size - 1))) != NULL) {
        memcpy(tm_name, ident, ident_size - 1);
        tm_name[ident_size - 2] = '\0';
    }
    printf("tm_name : %s , size =  %d", tm_name, strlen(tm_name));
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:
**tm_name : adress , size =  6**

Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to move the `printf` inside the `if` too.

Comment: it was just a dummie case, but i understand! thank you :)